# How do I get to a button placed over a pit in the Flooded Caves?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

I have found this new room layout:

[image: Flooded Room]

As you can see, the button to open the doors is placed over a pit. Is this a bug? How am I supposed to get out of this room without flight? Am I supposed to just wait for the doors to open automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say from the image, but there's no pit in the upper right corner of the room. There's a small pit just above the right entrance and that, combined to not knowing the color palette of the new levels tricked me into seeing a pit that wasn't there.

So, to get to the button, you can just walk there.

Comment: This is so embarassing...

Comment: LOL, anyway good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get out that room without flight seems to be bombing a door.

It's very strange because it's unusual, you should be able to clear a room without any special power. Maybe there are different mechanics that work for flooded level that we haven't discovered yet.